# Passing additional fields as part of PageRemote data annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, asp.net-identity

I have a cshtml page in the server side project of my Blazor Webassembly solution for editing user accounts that looks like this:

```
@page
@model TimesheetExpense.Server.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.EditModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit User";
}
@using TimesheetExpense.Shared.Dtos

<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>

<form id="user-form" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Input.UserId" name="UserId" class="form-control" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.LastName"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email"></span>
    </div>
    <button id="update-user-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

In the code behind, I'm trying to do some custom validation on the email field to check that the email address hasn't been used by another account. However, I don't want it to flag an issue if that email address is in use by the account I'm currently editing.

```
public partial class EditModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public EditModel(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [PageRemote(ErrorMessage = "Email address already in use.", HttpMethod = "POST", PageHandler = "CheckEmail", AdditionalFields = "UserId,__RequestVerificationToken")]
            public string? Email { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string? FirstName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string? LastName { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
        }

        private async Task LoadAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var userId = int.Parse(await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));

            Input = new InputModel
            {   
                Email = user.Email,
                FirstName = user.FirstName == null ? "" : user.FirstName,
                LastName = user.LastName == null ? "" : user.LastName,
                UserId = userId,
            };
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
            }

            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        public JsonResult OnPostCheckEmail(int UserId)
        {
            var userViaId = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(UserId.ToString()).Result;
            var userViaEmail = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email).Result;
            bool valid;
            if (userViaEmail == null)
                valid = true;
            else if (userViaEmail == userViaId)
                valid = true;
            else
                valid = false;
            return new JsonResult(valid);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string userId)
        {
           //Code removed for brevity
        }

    }
```

Whenever OnPostCheckEmail is called, UserId is always 0, even though the correct user id is showing in the input field on my form. How do I get it to pull through the correct user id?

My project is ASP.NET Core (.net 6.0) and my pages are based on the scaffolded identity pages.

Comment: In "<input asp-for="Input.UserId" name="UserId" class="form-control" />"  asp-for will generate name attribute in the html too.

Comment: Your PageRemote is  only added on email, you don't add another for UserId.